# is it possible to invoke native player and play video with that in j2me development?

Tags: video, java-me

i want to invoke/open the native player for my application.I have to open native video player and play my video with that video player. so please tell me is it possible to do this?
and if it is possible then which code snippet i have to use.and one thing i am developing my applicaion in j2me not in Qt SDk.

Comment: You can use Mobile Media API to play a video inside a Java ME application. Did you try it? See sample at http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/mmapioverview/index.html.

Comment: i have already used this coding and tried it on real device but i am not getting any mediacontrol like play,stop when any file is played.so what can i do for that?

Comment: Do you get an exception when you call Manager.createPlayer?

Comment: No. i am not getting any exception.

Comment: When you say "not getting any mediacontrol like play,stop", do you mean "buttons on the screen"? If so, Media API does not present any visual controls, it just plays the video.

Comment: so is there any code snippet that can help me to invoke default control of native video player in my application?

Answer (score 1):

The MIDlet class has the method named platformRequest(), but there is no guarantee it will work on many devices, where URL is the parameters. For example, to open native browser with parameter URL, just the real absolute URL, as "http://stackoverflow.com"

```
 public void openBrowser(String URL) {
        try {
            mainMIDlet.platformRequest(URL);
        } catch (ConnectionNotFoundException e) {
            // error
        }
    }
```

> If the URL specified is of the form tel:+558112345678, as specified in
>   RFC2806, then the platform MUST interpret this as a request to
>   initiate a voice call.
>
> Devices MAY choose to support additional URL schemes beyond the
>   requirements listed above.

More information see API JSR 118:
http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html

**TIP**

Uses the method getAppProperty (class MIDlet) or (class System):

```
public final String getAppProperty(String key)
```

to discovery values to URLs (parameters), like:

```
String platform = System.getProperty("microedition.platform");
```

Remember that every manufacturer has different types of specific parameters and combinations.